# Sorting App Versions in SQL Teradata

Tags: sorting, comparison, version, teradata-sql-assistant

There are different app versions such as 5.1.2, 5.1.5.6, 6.7, 8.1.2, etc. I want to select all the records with app version > 5.1, however I cannot do so using below code.

The below code obviously throws error:

```
select * from db1
where platform = 'Android'
and clientversion > 5.1
```

Comment: I'm using Teradata.

Comment: To be honest, I might recommend that you store the major, minor, etc. versions in separate columns.  You problem arises because you are trying to sort text, which is really numeric.